# Melting ice in a tray in space shuttle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy

We have an ice cube in a tray in a space shuttle. As the ice cube melts, the centre of mass shifts downward, so the tray should move downward to maintain the position of the centre of mass. Now, *some* force is required to move the tray, right? Where is this force coming from? Where does it transfer energy from? And when the tray stops, where does it transfer energy to?

Comment: Is this at zero G? If so, why exactly would the center of mass shift?

Comment: I think he is assuming that the ice, when melted, would still retain the general form of an ice cube in a tray, namely that it would have a flat water level and would not exit the tray. Whether this is true or not I'm not sure, since I feel like the surface tension might be a dominant enough force in 0G that the water will actually "wrap" itself around the tray, assuming the tray material is sufficiently non-hydrophobic.

Comment: If the water still remains in pools in the individual trays, then on the contrary, the tray should move upwards in order to compensate for the fact that the water level has moved downwards, so as to keep the center of mass the same. The work arises from the volume contraction during the phase transition of the water, sort of like the opposite of what happens when a gun fires a bullet using expanding gases.

Comment: If this is what was envisioned, I can post it as an answer.